# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (80,269,269) into shape (80,269,234)

Tags: python, arrays, scipy

`dataI` is of shape `(80,336,336)`

```
z= np.zeros([80,800,800], dtype= dataI.dtype)

v=np.zeros_like(z)

centres = [(100,200),(400,100), (600,300), (500,400), (600,500)]
zooms = [[1,1,1], [1,0.6,0.6], [1,0.7,0.7], [1,0.8,0.8], [1,0.9,0.9]]

for cent,zoom in zip(centres,zooms):

    dataZ = scipy.ndimage.zoom(dataI, zoom, order=3) 
    dimZ = dataZ.shape
    off = [max(c-s//2,0) for c,s in zip(cent,dimZ)]
    z[0:dataZ.shape[0],off[0]:off[0]+dimZ[1],off[1]:off[1]+dimZ[2]]=dataZ
```

I need to place the scaled data in big array `z`. By giving center positions, I need to place the data (if overlaps, take average of those values)

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    z[0:dataZ.shape[0],off[0]:off[0]+dimZ[1],off[1]:off[1]+dimZ[2]]=dataZ

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (80,269,269) into shape (80,269,234)
```

How could I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that slicing can go beyond the array extend, in that case only the elements that are in the extend of the array are returned:

```
>>> arr = np.ones((3, 3))
>>> arr[2:10, 2:10]   # that doesn't have shape (8, 8)!
array([[ 1.]])
```

So your calculation goes beyond the extend and thus the `z[0:dataZ.shape[0],off[0]:off[0]+dimZ[1],off[1]:off[1]+dimZ[2]]` isn't the shape you expect it to be!

I added some debug statements:

```
from scipy import ndimage  # better to import just submodules with scipy

# what you did

for cent, zoom in zip(centres, zooms):
    dataZ = ndimage.zoom(dataI, zoom, order=3) 
    dimZ = dataZ.shape
    off = [max(c - s // 2, 0) for c, s in zip(cent, dimZ)]
    print(off)
    print(np.s_[0:dataZ.shape[0],off[0]:off[0]+dimZ[1],off[1]:off[1]+dimZ[2]])
    z[0 : dataZ.shape[0],
      off[0] : off[0] + dimZ[1],
      off[1] : off[1] + dimZ[2]] = dataZ
```

This printed:

```
[60, 32]
(slice(0, 80, None), slice(60, 396, None), slice(32, 368, None))
[360, 0]
(slice(0, 80, None), slice(360, 562, None), slice(0, 202, None))
[560, 183]
(slice(0, 80, None), slice(560, 795, None), slice(183, 418, None))
[460, 266]
(slice(0, 80, None), slice(460, 729, None), slice(266, 535, None))
[560, 349]
(slice(0, 80, None), slice(560, 862, None), slice(349, 651, None))
```

And what I mentioned earlier applies here: The `slice(560, 862, None)` goes beyond the extend and thus you lack `62` items in the second dimension:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (80,302,302) into shape (80,240,302)
```

Easy fix: Increase the size of your `z`!

---

A related note: You know that `//` has higher precedence than `-`? So

```
max(c-s//2,0)     # is equivalent to max(c-(s//2), 0)
```